# Finding significant values from a series

Tags: pandas

I have a series with index and the count can be 0 to 1000.
I can select all the entries where the value is greater than 3
But after looking at the data, I decide to select all the entries where the value is more than 10 because some values are significantly higher than others!

```
s[s > 3].dropna()

-PB-[variable][variable]    8.0
-[variable] 15.0
-[variable][variable]   6.0
A-[variable][variable]  5.0
B   5.0
B-[variable][variable]  5.0
Book    4.0
Bus 8.0
Date    5.0
Dear    1609.0
MR  4.0
Man[variable]   4.0
Number[variable]    5.0
PM[variable]    4.0
Pickup  12.0
Pump[variable]  5.0
RJ  9.0
RJ-[variable]-PB-[variable][variable]   6.0
Time[variable]  6.0
[variable]  103.0
[variable][variable]    15.0
```

I have refined my query to something like this...

```
s[s > 10].dropna()

-[variable] 15.0
Dear    1609.0
Pickup  12.0
[variable]  103.0
[variable][variable]    15.0
```

Is there any function in pandas to return the significant entries. I can sort in descending order and select the first 5 or 10, but there is no guarantee that those entries will be very high compared to average. In that case I will prefer to select all entries.

In other words, I have decided the threshold of 10 in this case after looking at the data. Is there any method to select that value programmatically?

Comment: Do you mean you want a way to systematically identify a cutoff point for detecting outliers?

Comment: Yes. That is correct @Joe

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Selecting a threshold value with the [quntile](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.quantile.html) method might be a better solution, but still not the exact answer.

Comment: I agree with Vitaly here. Using some parameter describing the distribution of your data makes sense. This could be 2 or 3 times the standard deviation (if your data are roughly normally distributed) or choose some quantile as a cutoff point. E.g., `s = s[s<s.quantile(0.95)]` will give you the rows of the series below the 95th percentile.

Answer (score 0):

You can use .head function to select default top 5 row and .sort_values to sort in that dataframe. If you want to select top 10 then pass 10 in head function.

Simply call:

```
s[s['column_name'] > 10].sort_values(kind='quicksort', by='column_name_to_sort', ascending=False).head(10)
```